# Stretch Edges of Image in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scale

I have what I thought was a simple idea to implement in Photoshop, but I can't figure out how to do it.

What I'd like to do is take an image, and extend it left and right to fill a larger space by simply extending the last column of pixels on the left and right sides to the edges of the canvas (I might later try to fade the extensions).

I've tried doing this with Content Aware Scaling, but it simply stretches the image. I tried creating a protection region which is basically just all but the last few columns of pixels on each side, but I can't get figure out how to get the protection channel to "freeze" the bulk of the image -- it just continues to stretch it, which isn't what I want.

I tried creating a brush out of the last few columns of pixels, but when I use it, it simply paints the color in the upper left hand corner of the brush throughout the region being painted (i.e., the pattern is not being painted). I also failed trying to use the pattern stamping tool, too.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and, if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Using the **Single Column Marquee Tool** and selecting the left or right pixel column, click <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to scale horizontally.

[image]

Comment: Thanx, @Danielillo! That's a >>lot<< easier than what I did!

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: Be sure to unlock the aspect ratio on the toolbar at top, or it will be trying to stretch in both x and y directions. (May be obvious to more experienced PS users.)